# How to make a pager with MVCContrib and Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvccontrib-grid

I have a pager as follows:

```
@using MvcContrib.UI.Pager
@model MvcContrib.Pagination.IPagination

<p/>
  @Html.Pager(Model).First("First").Last("Last").Next("Next").Previous("Previous")
<p/>
```

Instead of displaying this:

> Showing 1 - 10
>   of 10841 First |
>   Previous | Next |
>   Last

It displays this:

```
<div class='pagination'><span class='paginationLeft'>Showing 1 - 10 of 10841 </span><span class='paginationRight'>First | Previous | <a href="/Home/Events?page=2">Next</a> | <a href="/Home/Events?page=1085">Last</a></span></div>
```

I also downloaded a sample project from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Grid_Paging_In_MVC3.aspx?display=Print), but when I run it, I get the same problem.

What could possibly be the problem? Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Care to point out the specific issue? The HTML looks fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor automatically encodes html if you return a String. It won't encode Html if you return an IHtmlString.

Does the pager method return a String instead of IHtmlString?

Try using Html.Raw. This method will convert a String to an IHtmlString.

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Pager(Model).First("First").Last("Last").Next("Next").Previous("Previous"))
```

Comment: I had to do `@Html.Raw(Html.Pager(Model).First("First").Last("Last").Next("Next").Previous("Previous").ToString())` but otherwise it worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

The reason it works in the sample project and not your project is because in the sample project they're using the `@Html.Pager` in a partial page which is then called on the main page using `@{Html.RenderPartial();}` when rendering like that the rendered string from the `Pager` is output as html rather than encoded html.

If you need to use the pager without the subpages then you'll need to wrap the call in `Html.Raw` as Linkgoron suggested as the `Html.Pager` defaults to using the `ToString` which returns a `string` and not `IHtmlString`

Comment: Your technique of using @Html.Raw(Html.Pager(...).ToString()) worked for me. +1.