# Html.RenderPartial is not rendering view correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I create a **MvcContrib.UI.Grid** in my ASP.NET C# MVC 3 applicatio. I create pageer for this

grid.Please see my pager code

> @using MvcContrib.UI.Pager
>
> @using MvcContrib.Pagination
>
> @model IPagination
>
> @Html.Pager(Model).First("First").Last("Last").Next("Next").Previous("Previous")

call the Pager.cshtml in my View. please see the below image

[image]

But finally it's rendering like.

[image]

I am clueless. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a pager with MVCContrib and Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557139/how-to-make-a-pager-with-mvccontrib-and-razor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are writing a plain `string` with the `@` sign to the response razor automatically html encodes it for you.

Because `Html.Pager` returns just a plain `string` containing the html so you need to use `Html.Raw` to prevent the automating encoding in Razor:

So you need to change your Pager partial view to:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Pager(Model)
              .First("First")
              .Last("Last")
              .Next("Next")
              .Previous("Previous").ToString())
```